# Auto create campaign member

Tags: campaign-member

I need to create a campaign member based off of a custom field value on the lead object. I'm a newbie to the world of apex but hopefully this will better help me understand the process.

When

Custom_Field__c = My New Campaign

CREATE
----------- >>> New campaign member of campaign (My New Campaign)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is job for trigger! :)
As you are newbie I will give you some tips to show you way, but details you should find by yourself ;)

So, create trigger for lead - best idea should be after insert/update:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm

In trigger create new instance of campaignMember (fill all required fields based on your lead)
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm

then insert your instance of campaignMember and enjoy your new campaignMember :D

To be honest I think this question is not specific enough and could be easly close.
So try follow steps I described and in case of any errors or problems please ask again.
The forum is place where you could  find help with your problems - not someone who make your job.

Comment: Thank you so very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: This, as Arthur Described, if you want to expand this logic more, I suggest having a CampaignCode for your Campaigns and a custom field on your Lead/Contact which you can query Campaigns and create Campaign Members dynamically as described